# Prove that $f^{-1}(f(I))=I$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals, ring-homomorphism

Let $f\in Hom(R,R')$ be a surjective map and let $I$ be an ideal of $R$

Assume that $Ker(f)\subseteq I$ , prove that $f^{-1}(f(I))=I$

My work ,

$Ker(f)\subseteq I \Rightarrow f^{-1}(\left \{ 0_{R'} \right \})\subseteq I \Rightarrow \left \{ 0_{R'} \right \} \subseteq f(I)\Rightarrow f^{-1}(\left \{ 0_{R'} \right \})\subseteq f^{-1}(f(I))\Rightarrow Ker(f)\subseteq f^{-1}(f(I))$

Here I'm stucked

($R$ and $R'$ are commutative and unitaty rings and $f$ is unital)

Comment: Note that $\left \{ 0_{R'} \right \} \subseteq f(I)$ is trivial as $0\in I$. You may not infer anything significant from here. Rather than working "set-theoretically", I advise you to prove the result using double inclusion. Take an element of one set, prove that it belongs to the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Let $f\colon R\to R'$ be a surjective ring homomorphism and $I$ an ideal of $R$. Then $f^{-1}(f(I))=I$ if and only if $\ker f\subseteq I$.

One direction is easy: if $f^{-1}(f(I))=I$, then clearly $\ker f\subseteq I$, because $0\in f(I)$. (This is what you attempted, so not really relevant for your problem.)

For the converse direction, note that $I\subseteq f^{-1}(f(I))$ holds regardless of $I$ being an ideal. Thus you just need to prove the converse inclusion.

Suppose $x\in f^{-1}(f(I))$. Then $f(x)\in f(I)$, by definition, so there is $y\in I$ such that $f(x)=f(y)$.

Can you go on? What can you say about $x-y$?

Comment: x-y belongs to ker(f)

Comment: Since f(x)-f(y)=0 then f(x-y)=0 then ....

Comment: So x-y belongs to I by hypothesis

Answer (score 4):

More generally, show that $f^{-1}(f(I)) = \ker f + I$. For $x ∈ R$,
\begin{align*}
x ∈ f^{-1}(f(I)) &\iff f(x) ∈ f(I) \\
&\iff ∃y ∈ I\colon~f(x) = f(y) \\
&\iff ∃y ∈ I\colon~x - y ∈ \ker f\\
&\iff …?
\end{align*}

Comment: Do we need surjectivity? I can't see where it is used

Comment: @Evariste No you don’t.